# Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'> when query'ing python 2 class

Tags: python, django

Django has following build in class:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ResetPasswordToken(models.Model):
```

I'm writing a test and want to check if there is a reset password token in db for a specific user. So I do:

```
token = ResetPasswordToken.objects.filter().all()
```

Hower python has problems with this:

```
Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

I think this is because I am using python 3 and above the model there is a `'@python_2_unicode_compatible'`?

How can I do this correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of the [decorator python_2_unicode_compatible](https://github.com/benjaminp/six/blob/master/six.py#L948) for python3 it does nothing.

and error about queryset not about model. Please check on what python you are running your tests. and provide more description if possible (like lines you run in console)